# How and where to view all deleted posts?

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request

I’m asking this because, I forgot how to view a list of all self deleted posts and deleted posts by moderators on each site. And I really need to know how to do that.

**Q-1:** Can anyone please, show me where to see in order to see all deleted posts from any site so that I can undelete some of them?

**Q-2:** Can you make in such that everyone can go and view all deleted posts from each site on each telephone including iphone6 and not only on pc?

**Q-3:** Can anyone please allow users to edit a self deleted posts on any telephone?

If the question title is wrong according to the question below, can you please edit it?

Answer (score 0):

Your own delete posts can be found by searching for [`deleted:1`](https://islam.stackexchange.com/search?q=deleted%3A1).  This doesn't work as expected on my iPhone.

StackExchange mobile app development is reported as frozen on meta.SE.

> New feature work on the apps has pretty much been frozen for the time being.  -- [Kasra Rahjerdi](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300389/351283), StackExchange mobile team, August, 2017.